# Notification when waking up from hibernation C#

Tags: c#, .net, hibernation

Is there a way to get a notification (event) in my C# 2.0 application when the system **wakes up from** hibernation?

My application is running in system tray at the moment the system goes into hibernation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450902/windows-cpu-power-management-apis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx):

> *SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged Event*
>
> Occurs when the user suspends **or resumes** the system.